# WordPress Custom Post Type Link to Posts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a custom post type named "University" in WordPress.

That university post type is then displayed in a dropdown on the user screen, so each user can be assigned to a university. I do have a form which automatically assigns them when they register for an account.

I need to link that University with the user, as I basically need to do a count for how many post articles have been published for a certain university.

Currently I have the following SQL query, which displays the total number of posts for the users who's ID's are 1 and 10:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    wp_usermeta.meta_value,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_author IN (1,10)) AS 'total_posts'
    FROM
        wp_usermeta
    INNER JOIN
        wp_posts ON wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_posts.post_author
    WHERE
        wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'university_field'
    ORDER BY
        total_posts DESC
```

My questions is, how can I loop through just the universities and get the ID's of the users associated? Then how can I use this to display the universities in order of how many articles they have?

I am not sure if Custom Post Type is the best approach for this, as the university will require it's own page. If this is best to create a taxonomy in posts, then I would welcome feedback. However this needs to be automatic, so every article written should automatically know the user and what university, instead of them ticking their own university each time.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks so much.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want.  "Link that University with the user" - HOW?  And then, you mention "post articles" - ok, so are you saying that a university has "published" an article based on the author's relationship with the university? And how are you "Associating" the user with the university - meaning, what does that DATA structure look like?

Comment: I am currently linking the user to the university by adding a custom field to the user screen, which is a select field listing all of the universities from the custom post type. So I have that data within the usermeta field, which also has the users ID. An author has published an article, but in the setup would have a university assigned so would automatically work out it's from that Uni. How would you advise best setting this up knowing what I want?

Comment: Answering your question is difficult when you don't answer the questions that we ask.  I asked what the data structure looks like...